# Smart download tool?

Tags: download

Is there a SMART download tool I can use?  I am trying to download a file that is 1.5 GB. I am using AT&T net service and I am using Windows 8.  I am using Firefox 18, and also the computer has I.E. 10.   The AT&T net service breaks every 20 minutes or something is wrong. I have tried to download the file many times over the past week, but always a failure. At times IE or Firefox downloads 10MB, or 100MB, or 150 MB, or 250 MB, but then says failure.  Then I have to start all over again. Is there a smart download tool, that when the connection breaks, instead of starting over with the download it can continue with previous download from the point of the failure.

I am in a wheelchair and cannot move much and I have no access to any other computer or service.  thank you

Answer (score 2):

Internet Download Manager.

U can resume downloads and its much faster than most browsers.

http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html

Orbit Downloader

http://www.orbitdownloader.com/

Comment: No money to buy. Even with Windows 8, no smart download tool?

Comment: it should be enough for the 1.5 gb file? it has a 30 day trail version

Comment: thank you! but this is a temp solution.I am in a wheelchair, and money is tight. And when one is stuck in wheelchair all life, one downloads often.

Comment: +1 for Orbit Downloader (which is free). But the server where you are downloading it has to support resuming of downloads, otherwise there is not much you can do about it (except downloading it somewehre else and then transferring it to you)

Comment: Yes, maybe that is the problem. The server is not supporting the resuming part.

Comment: I tried Orbit. The problem the webpage needs a password to reach the download page.  It can only be done through IE or firefox. Orbit not working. I will keep trying.

Comment: In Orbit Downloader go to Tools>Preferences>Site Manager. In That you should be able to add your site username and password. Should work! :)